# How do i display text in the middle?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is my site, http://www.defensionem.com/schwellenpflug/

I want to shift the text from both the directions in the middle. So as the text is in the center and is easy to read and looks good. I can only add custom CSS so please advice.

Using Firebug,

I tried this:

```
.main-content{
padding-left:250px;
}
```

Which works but it isn't exactly in the middle. I tried changing the padding values and noticed it also has to do something with the sidebar side.

I'm confused.

I tried text-align:center; but it only aligns the format of the text and doesn't bring it in the middle.

Comment: post `css` and `html` code here..

Comment: I don't think I can do that, its a Wordpress site. I can add Custom CSS though. I tried figuring out using Firebug and inspect element. Thanks!

Comment: neither your link is working???

Comment: we need a working link or `css` and `html` code to help you!

Comment: Sorry sir, I'll try fixing that. Try this link. http://www.defensionem.com/schwellenpflug/ Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this style

```
.main-content {
display: block;
width: 80%;  // if fixed width then replace 80% with 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**To align DIV in center**

```
div {
display: block;
width: 80%; //works only if width is less than 100% or fixed like 250px
margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: ya.. I checked it.. Wait.. for few mins

Comment: Sure Sir. I wanna make the text appear in the middle, that is, it is equally the same distance from left and right sides. :)

Comment: well i checked your site.. It have very messy css. your `.main-content` is `float:left` and its width is already 100% so you have to do a lot of home work i will give an exam to help you

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` does not work with `float` and `width:100%`

Comment: Sure! Well it is a Wordpress theme sir, so it does have unnecessary codings.

Comment: So how do I clean and go about it? What do I do? Thanks again! :)

Comment: well `main-content__inside` this is the class you should play with